# Where is sympy library used?

Tags: python, libraries

I'd admire the functions of [sympy library](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/), what it does is really awesome. The integration functions are really few guys intellectual work. But where exactly we use them practically on computers? If not sympy, do we really need such libraries? If we need them, what languages would satisfy our needs?

Comment: You'd use SymPy if you were writing algorithms involving advanced math in Python.

Comment: do we have a similar library in written in C

Comment: Check out this Gnu Scientific Library for C developers.<br />
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/ <br />
Checkout more libraries here:<br />
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries<br />
and here:<br />
http://www.helsinki.fi/~fyl_tlpk/luento/ohj-13-GSL-e.html<br />

Answer (score 1):

In some scientific fields (from experience: mostly mathematics and physics; most engineers prefer to use numerical approximations), often is interesting to calculate exact forms for integrals, derivatives, solutions of differential equations etc...

Thus, SymPy becomes useful for those applications. Also, I imagine it being useful for educational applications (where an exact answer, at least for simple problems, is interesting)